# Select all in gvim via CMD+A

Tags: macos, vim

sometimes CTRL+A, CTRL+C is a very smooth way to just do that what it says. Copy all content to the systems clipboard. Unfortunately it isn't working as expected these days. CMD+A (I'm on a Mac) just doesn't select all Lines. So here are my two questions:

1. How can I map CMD+A again to select all lines in the actual file?
2. As I am asking, how can I map gg to go to the Top of the file again?

Best,
Plattenschieber

Comment: Are you doing this in macvim? or from the terminal? As for the second question what does gg do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The equivalent of GVim on Mac OS X is MacVim. Are you using MacVim or are you *really* using GVim in XQuartz?
2. In MacVim, Cmd+a selects the whole buffer and Cmd+c copies what is selected to the clipboard. If that's not the case, either *you* have messed with something or MacVim is not installed properly (I wonder how a simple drag and drop could fail).
3. If you are using Vim in a terminal emulator, why did you write "gvim"? The Cmd key can only be intercepted by MacVim, CLI Vim doesn't recognize it so Cmd+a won't work. You should get used to the Vim way:

   ```
   :%y +
   ```

Comment: You are right, I am using MacVim. I'm used to invoke it via gvim in cli. I removed my misplaced map for gg and since then I can use CMD+A again.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this two mappings with your vim:

```
nnoremap <c-a> ggVG
nnoremap <c-c> "*y
```

But I won't recommend those mappings..

Comment: This maps ctrl not cmd.

Comment: @FDinoff  I know it is a key from apple keyboard, but actually I don't know what is `CMD` key. :( I thought it is same as `ctrl`.. I would remove the answer if it shows the wrong direction...  I have a HHKB, there are two annoying 'CMD' keys too. under windows, they are win keys. but on linux, nothing happens when I press them.

Comment: The CMD key physically replaces the windows key. However in mac os it replaces the functionality of the control key. Mac still has a control key which gets used as a modifier for other things. If you were to dual boot into windows the command key would behave exactly like the windows key. So saying its the same as ctrl is only sorta correct. vim captures the actual control key in these commands not the command key.

Comment: @FDinoff thx for the explanation. I have Zero experience with apple system, glad to know it.

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented in `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim`. If you don't need all typical (Windows) keyboard shortcuts, just selectively grab the corresponding section (perhaps adapting the mappings left-hand side):

```
" CTRL-A is Select all
noremap <C-A> gggH<C-O>G
inoremap <C-A> <C-O>gg<C-O>gH<C-O>G
cnoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
onoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
snoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
xnoremap <C-A> <C-C>ggVG
```

#### RE: Your additional question

> how can I map gg to go to the Top of the file again

Don't ask multiple questions (and if you do, please provide more context!) Do you have a mapping for `gg`?! Find out who defined it:

```
:verbose nmap gg
```

should tell you. If you cannot remove the unwanted mapping, `:nunmap gg` will do.

Comment: This maps ctrl not cmd.